# Did India face criticism from U.S. officials for its mercantilist policies?

Tags: united-states, india, international, trade

Did India face criticism from U.S. officials for its mercantilist policies?

https://itif.org/publications/2019/11/18/2019-global-mercantilist-index-ranking-nations-distortive-trade-policies/

Looking at this index that measures how mercantilistic a country is, we see that India is right next to China in terms of how mercantilist a country is. Mercantilist was defined by the report as the tendency to pursue policies that seek to grow nations’ innovation-based firms and industries through policies such as local production requirements, export subsidies, weak intellectual property (IP) protection, discrimination against foreign firms, economy-specific technical requirements, and data localization requirements.

I am wondering if India faced any criticism from U.S. officials regarding its mercantilist policies, because I remember a lot of U.S. officials doing so against China, but I never heard any of them do the same against India.

Comment: "The United States is not included in this report, as the structure of the analysis, including analyzing *trade-weighted impacts* and the effects of countries’ policies toward advanced technology industries, orient the report toward assessing *how other nations’ mercantilist practices affect the United States*". Just a fair warning to anyone reading the report, that it's about US trade specifically, not an assessment of national policies per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes. But more recently they've preferred to resolve those differences without  resorting to WTO arbitration, [e.g.](https://ustr.gov/about-us/policy-offices/press-office/press-releases/2023/september/united-states-announces-resolution-outstanding-wto-poultry-dispute-india)

> September 08, 2023
>
> United States Trade Representative Katherine Tai today announced that the United States and India have agreed to resolve their last outstanding dispute at the World Trade Organization, India — Measures Concerning the Importation of Certain Agricultural Products (DS 430). As part of the agreement, India also agreed to reduce tariffs on certain U.S. products, including frozen turkey, frozen duck, fresh blueberries and cranberries, frozen blueberries and cranberries, dried blueberries and cranberries, and processed blueberries and cranberries. [...]
>
> In June, the United States and India agreed to terminate six outstanding disputes at the World Trade Organization. India also agreed to reduce tariffs on certain U.S. products, including chickpeas, lentils, almonds, walnuts, apples, boric acid, and diagnostic reagents.

Someone can probably look up those 6. (There's a link in the source but it's broken.)